Accept-Ranges different from nginx and apache
Using the default configuration, I get this from nginx
curl -I -r 0-1023  http://localhost:8080/example.root
HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content
Server: nginx/1.25.5
Date: Tue, 21 May 2024 23:02:29 GMT
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Content-Length: 1024
Last-Modified: Tue, 21 May 2024 21:12:56 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
ETag: "664d0e58-4cd4ae1"
Content-Range: bytes 0-1023/80562913

and this from apache
HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content
Date: Tue, 21 May 2024 23:08:58 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.59 (Unix)
Last-Modified: Tue, 21 May 2024 21:12:56 GMT
ETag: "4cd4ae1-618fd482c4c5a"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 1024
Content-Range: bytes 0-1023/80562913

The main different is the Accept-Ranges: bytes is not present in nginx. Apache seems to be very verbose since the response is 206, but is there any standard?
